# Vapor app on Cloud Run throwing when connecting to Cloud SQL

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, vapor

I've built a Vapor app and am trying to deploy it to Google cloud run. At the same time I'm trying to connect my app to a Cloud SQL instance using unix sockets as it's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#node.js). There was also a issue opened on Vapor's postgres library [here](https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit/issues/103) that mentions being successful using unix sockets to connect from cloud run.

## Setup

My code looks like this:

```swift
let postgresConfig = PostgresConfiguration(unixDomainSocketPath: Environment.get("DB_SOCKET_PATH") ?? "/cloudsql",
                                                   username: Environment.get("DATABASE_USERNAME") ?? "vapor_username",
                                                   password: Environment.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD") ?? "vapor_password",
                                                   database: Environment.get("DATABASE_NAME") ?? "vapor_database")
app.databases.use(.postgres(configuration: postgresConfig), as: .psql)
```

I've also tested to see if the environment variables are there using this snippet, which didn't throw the `fatalError`.

```swift
if Environment.get("DB_SOCKET_PATH") == nil {
    fatalError("No environment variables found...")
}
```

My `DB_SOCKET_PATH` looks like `cloudsql/project-id:us-central1:sql-instance-connection-name/.s.PGSQL.5432`

I've also set up the correct user and database in the Cloud SQL instance, as well as enabled public ip connections.

## Whats happening?

When I deploy this image to google cloud run, it throws the error: `Fatal error: Error raised at top level: connect(descriptor:addr:size:): No such file or directory (errno: 2): file Swift/ErrorType.swift, line 200`

## What have you done?

I tried testing unix socket connections on my local machine, and I found that when I had the incorrect unix socket, it would through this error.

I also tried commenting out all migration and connection code, which fixed the error, and narrowed it down to the `PostgresConfiguration` code.

## What are you trying to do?

I'm trying to figure out how to connect my cloud run app to a cloud sql instance. Am I missing a configuration somewhere on my instances? Or am I making a mistake with my unix path/vapor implementation?

Comment: So it seems that socket file doesn't exists. You could try to find a way to check existence of the file, maybe its path is different every time you launch the server

Comment: Your path should be `/cloudsql/project-id:us-central1:sql-instance-connection-name` there is no other folder like `/.s.PGSQL.5432` on it.

Comment: @Pentium10 I'll try it without the /.s.PGSQL.5432 on it.

Comment: @thecoolwinter did the suggestion fix your issue?

Comment: @3366784 yes, it did. I ended up reading GPC's documentation closer for connecting through unix sockets and found that cloud run needs a special connector instance to connect using that method. Instead, you should give your SQL instance a public IP in your project and connect using that.